# 'webpack' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Archivo .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

Archivo webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Archivo package.json:

```
{
  "name": "scaffold",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.3"
  }
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando 'webpack' esto es lo que me aparece:

webpack : El término 'webpack' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el 
nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ webpack
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (webpack:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

Comment: Hiciste npm i webpack -g ?

Comment: No, no lo instalé de forma global porque no se aconsejaba. Leí que puede generar conflictos con tus diferentes proyectos. ¿Vos crees que esa es la solución?

Comment: si no es global instalalo en el proyecto , quita el `-g`

Comment: Si miras el package.json te darás cuenta que lo tengo instalado.

Comment: Lo tienes como debe dependencia es distinto

Comment: ejecuta el comando `npm view webpack ` si no te devuelve nada debes instalarlo, probablemente al instalarlo  paso un error

Comment: ¿Se debe instalar como "dependencies" y no como "devDependencies"?

Comment: Tuve una forma de ejecutarlo directamente desde su carpeta en node_modules/bin/webpack (creo que así era, no estoy en mi pc ahora). Pero no me parece normal, ya que en donde sea que busque siempre lo ejecutan tan sólo con "webpack"

Comment: Ejecuté el `npm view webpack` y sí me devuelve algo.